# Why is having a member variable ("attribute") named `None` forbidden?

Tags: python, python-3.x, null, attributes

Why is having a member variable ("attribute") named `None` forbidden?

```
x = object()
x.y = 55
x.watermelon = "green red and white"
x.None = None
```

Error:

```
File "D:/FILE_MGMT_PYTHON/fgfghfghfgh.py", line 9
    x.None = None
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code
```

Comment: `None` is a keyword, the name of a special kind of object.  In general keywords are not allowed as attributes,  Nor can you use them as ordinary variables.

Comment: E.g. with dictionaries you can do like this: `x = dict(); x[None] = None` and this works, while above answer and the one provided in the answer says it correctly that the reserved keyword cannot be used as attributes.

Comment: It's a keyword. Just use `NONE` instead (or perhaps `Null`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords):

> The following identifiers are used as reserved words, or keywords of the language, and cannot be used as ordinary identifiers. They must be spelled exactly as written here:
>
> ... `None` ...

Comment: There are two sets of words in the python language I would like to focus on for a moment: 1) **built-in functions** (no import statement required) such as `type`, `isinstance`, `hasattr`, `getattr`, etc... and 2) language **keywords** such as `class`, `def`, `pass`, `None`. It seems fairly arbitrary which rules apply to which word. Why allow people to shadow `i instance`, but not shadow `None`? To be consistent, I would think that you would either disallow shadowing both or allow shadowing both.

Comment: Also, `x.None`, and `getattr(x, "None")`, are clearly not the same as `None`. I do not see why `None` can't be a reserved language keyword while still allowing attributes to be named `None` as in `x.None` There is no ambiguity between the two, even for a fairly unintelligent lexer and parser.

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone: If you allow one keyword in one particular context where it can be disambiguated, the question arises of why not other keywords in other contexts, and then you get stuff like `x.if` and `class Foo: None = 3` and `[for.for for for in for]` and the syntax and parser both become confusing messes. Python's syntax is intended to be simple.

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone: Also see [PEP 3099](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3099/): "Simple is better than complex. This idea extends to the parser. Restricting Python's grammar to an LL(1) parser is a blessing, not a curse. It puts us in handcuffs that prevent us from going overboard and ending up with funky grammar rules like some other dynamic languages that will go unnamed, such as Perl."